# Merging distinct from one column and sum from others in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have Multiple Rows of same product with different Qty.
I want single row of each product by doing some of Qty in datatable in vb.net

Comment: Can you be clearer about where you're doing this? Is it in the database, so you need to do it in SQL, or is it in ASP.NET? If the latter, what is your data access technology? Entity Framework, so you want the syntax in LINQ? Also, have you made an attempt and therefore you have some sample code you would like some help with?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group by the product and sum the quantity per group?

You could use LINQ's `GroupBy` + `Sum` and fill a second table with the same schema:

```
Dim productGroups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Product"))
Dim aggregatedTable As DataTable = dt.Clone() ' empty table, same columns
For Each grp In productGroups
    Dim newRow = aggregatedTable.Rows.Add()
    Dim sumOfQuantity As Int32 = grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Int32)("Qty"))
    newRow.SetField("Product", grp.Key)
    newRow.SetField("Qty", sumOfQuantity)
Next
```

The same with query syntax if you prefer it:

```
Dim productGroups = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
                    Group row By Product = row.Field(Of String)("Product") Into Group
```

Comment: Hey but if my dt is datatable then?

Comment: I have tried your code but it is giving me an error that Group BY is not a member of 'System.data.EnumrableRowcollection(Of system.data.datarow)'

Comment: You have to use at least. NET 3.5 to be able to use linq. Also remember to add Imports System.Linq